# How to save unused data (materials, images, meshes... etc)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials

It is my understanding that when materials for eg, are not attached to an object and you save the blend file - the materials are gone when you re-open the file?

How can you keep your materials - even when they are not attached to an object ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Click the `F` icon:

[image]

This adds a *fake user* which acts like an object using the material, preventing it from being deleted.

See the [reference manual](https://www.blender.org/manual/data_system/data_blocks.html#fake-user) page on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

For everyone still wondering, like I did today, the 'F' icon was now changed to a shield icon and turns white with a checkmark when enabled.

Comment: I recommend you edit the existing answer to include details about this change.